# How to retrieve the records from coredata between two dates that are stored as NSStrings in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Am using coredata for my app.Am storing the due dates as `NSStrings` in the coredata. Now am in a situation to retrieve the records between two dates.(my due dates are stored in the format of ex:29/8/14) if i want to retrieve the records between for ex :29/8/14 to 28/10/14,how can iachieve that?Is there any possibility?

my code to insert the records is

```
    -(void)insertBill:(NSMutableDictionary *)bill
    {
    Bill *info = nil;

    info = [self getBills:bill];

    if(info!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Bill  already Exists");
    }
    else
    {////NSLog(@"adding new");

        if(info==nil)
            info = [NSEntityDescription
                    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Bill"
                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"billId"] forKey:@"billId"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"category"] forKey:@"category"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"billName"] forKey:@"billName"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"account"] forKey:@"account"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"amount"] forKey:@"amount"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"recurring"] forKey:@"recurring"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"dueDate"] forKey:@"dueDate"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"reminder"] forKey:@"reminder"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"dailyReminder"] forKey:@"dailyReminder"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"time"] forKey:@"time"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"notes"] forKey:@"notes"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"imagePath"] forKey:@"imagePath"];
        [info setValue:[bill valueForKey:@"recurringPeriod"] forKey:@"recurringPeriod"];
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Saved Successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

and getBills method to check duplication

```
  - (Bill *)getBills:(NSMutableDictionary *)data

    {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Bill" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    if([data valueForKey:@"billId"])
    {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(billId == %@)", [data objectForKey:@"billId"]]];
    }
    NSError *error;
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSArray* dataa =  [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if(dataa.count>0)
        return [dataa objectAtIndex:0];
     else
        return nil;

}
```

please give me a solution.And please tell me can we store NSDate as NSString in this situation? otherwise is it neccessry to change the datatype of 'duedate' to NSDate?
Help me regarding this please..Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you store your date data types as `NSDate` attributes in your data model.

Answer (score 0):

Okay ,you can store an NSDate as a string.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:yourNSDate];
```

But, its always better to store date in the NSDate format rather that storing it as a string. NSDate would just be a large integer denoting the seconds elapsed since well a long time ago. So if you change your data type to NSDate its easier to write predicates which offer better flexibility.

Here's an example

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"billId == %@ && (dueDate >= %@ && dueDate <= %@", [data objectForKey:@"billId"],fromDate,toDate]];
```

Note here fromDate and toDate are two NSDate instances.

Comment: I used the datatype as NSDate in coredata.Now its working fine.Thanks for the reply navin.-)

Comment: Glad to help !, i mentioned that in the second line of the answer :) Don forget to vote up :)